Http response status 201 CREATED without Location
In HTTP standard: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.3.2 it says that for 201 CREATED:

The primary resource created by the request is identified
by either a Location header field in the response or, if no Location
field is received, by the effective request URI.

I have a POST endpoint that creates a resource and returns the created resource's DTO in the response body. I don't want to return a location, it is useless for our use case and it would be difficult to say for sure for the backend app what the absolute path would be as it sits behind a proxy.
My question is: is it still in agreement with the standard to omit the Location header? The front-end app can access the resource by calling the appropriate path and using the id provided in the body (I suppose this might be the "effective request URI"?), and it also has the entire resource in the response body.
One of my colleagues suggests I should use 200 OK instead - I doubt that's a good idea but I include it here in case I'm wrong.

No, the body is not part of the request URI. If you are POSTing to /foobar/, and the resource that creates can afterwards be requested by making a GET request for /foobar/, then you could leave out the Location header. If posting to that endpoint multiple times would create multiple resources, which can then in turn be requested using /foobar/1, /foobar/2 - then you should return that URI via a Location header.

"The front-end app can access the resource by calling the appropriate path and using the id provided in the body" - that would be a POST request then ...? That would mean at that point you would rather be "violating" HTTP standards, because reading a resource should not use POST in the first place, but GET.

@C3roe no, what I meant was that after creating the resource, frontend can access it by making GET request to '/resource/1' where '1' is the id of the created resource. And to the earlier comment: then would relative path be appropriate like "/foobar/1" instead of "https://example.com/api/foobar/1"?
